# How to use php code inside html?

Tags: php, html

For example, i want to make a page where you enter two numbers in textboxes and when you click the button it calls the php file which sums them and then outputs the result in some kind of a label (sorry if the expressions are wrong, i'm used to c# reference)

So how to do it? :D

Answer (score 6):

I would not suggest using PHP to add to integers it is unnecessary. You can accomplish this very simply with JavaScript without refreshing the page. You can also use AJAX to accomplish this without reloading the entire page. I would suggest JavaScript though.

```
<html>
  <head>
        <title>Input tutorial</title>
        <script language="javascript">
                function addNumbers()
                {
                        var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
                        var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
                        var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
                        ansD.value = val1 + val2;
                }
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
        value1 = <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="1"/>
        value2 = <input type="text" id="value2" name="value2" value="2"/>
        <input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Click here" onclick="javascript:addNumbers()"/>
        Answer = <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" value=""/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

PHP is a server side language which is executed by the Server, not the client (browser). In order to do what you mentioned the page would need to be reloaded.

If you want to reload the page with the new data, that is possible, if you do not want to have to reload the page, you will need to use another language like Javascript to do this.

Another possibility is using Javascript to execute a PHP script for results.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make some sort of server request either by requesting an entirely new page or using AJAX. PHP will only run on the server.

Ideally, if it doesn't have to be PHP, I'd do it in Javascript. If you're learning PHP, then I'd suggest following a [tutorial](http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2009/07/27/add-two-numbers-4/).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a form and the simplest method would be like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">

    <input type="text" name="int1" /> 
    + 
    <input type="text" name="int2" />
    = 
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $int1 = $_POST['int1'];
        $int2 = $_POST['int2'];
        echo $int1 + $int2;
    }
    ?>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Get Sum" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Triggers two notices on the first page load, both "undefined index" errors for your POST vars.

Comment: Good catch. I edited this to handle the notices, slipped my mind.